# Ionic- display picture taken with camera on same page

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-scope, ionic-view

I'm trying to display image captured through camera on the same page without visiting phone's memory. Somewhat like watsapp, the way we click and upload right away from there only. So, it is like we capture something and display it automatically on the same page, where we have capture button.

```
 .controller('CameraCtrl', function($scope, $cordovaCamera) {

  document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {

    var options = {
      quality: 50,
      destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
      sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
      allowEdit: true,
      encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
      targetWidth: 100,
      targetHeight: 100,
      popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
      saveToPhotoAlbum: false,
      correctOrientation:true
    };

    $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function(imageData) {
        var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
        image.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
       }, function(err) {
      // error
    });

   }, false);

})
```

app.js

```
 .state('tab.detail', {
  url: '/new-order/id',
  views: {
    'tab-new': {
      templateUrl: 'templates/detail.html',
      controller: 'DetailCtrl'
    }
  }
})

.state ('camera',{
  url:'/camera',
  templateUrl: 'templates/detail.html',
  controller:'CameraCtrl'
})
```

html

```
       <ion-content>
         <div>
           <div class="col text-right">
             <p>
               <a href="#/camera" class="camera-icon" ><i class="icon ion-camera"></i></a>
             </p>
           </div>
      <p>
        <img ng-src="image.src" />
      <p>
   </div>
 </ion-content>
```

Comment: Hi **kk19**, Your code looks good according to the doc http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/camera/ . Can you please tell me which error are you getting to display image.
Thanks

Comment: There is no error. Camera works fine, image gets stored but I need to display it on my page, the same page that we have camera option on. Without accessing my phone gallery

Comment: I have added app.js code above check it. Camera works fine captures image but I need to display it on the same page that we have camera option.

Comment: please share your html.

Answer (score 0):

you need to declare image.src on the scope like this `$scope.image.src="data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;`

Then in you html bind the image like this `<img ng-src="image.src"/>`

Comment: I have added html code and tried as per your instructions but it shows broken image instead of taking url automatically. And, I am able to click on camera only once means if I have to use camera again I have to close app and re-open it again

Comment: Yes I have used that for now but still no help

Comment: http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/camera/  I have used first controller from this link not second one

Comment: any other way possible